# How to sum three metrics for each host given a wildcard list of hosts in Graphite Web?

Tags: graphite

I've got three metrics "memoryFree", "memoryBuffered", "memoryCached". These metrics appear under each of the ec2 hosts in the following metric tree:
`system.radar123.collectd.ec2*_com.memory.`
For each ec2 host I would like to sum the three metrics and display the sum. How to do this? Is there a graphite web function that will iterate over the wildcard and treat each one separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by `groupByNode`:

`groupByNode(system.radar123.collectd.ec2*_com.memory-{buffered,cached,free},3,\"sumSeries\")`